# Trying to call Replicate API

Tags: reactjs, next.js, replicate

When I try to execute this POST request I get a cors-policy error. If I set mode to no-cors I get a caught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Illegal invocation error. What can I do against it?

```
// POST request to Replicate to start the image restoration generation process
let startResponse = await fetch(
  "https://api.replicate.com/v1/predictions",
  {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: "Token " + process.env.REPLICATE_API_KEY,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      version:
        "d55b9f2dcfb156089686b8f767776d5b61b007187a4e1e611881818098100fbb",
      input: {
        image: imageUrl,
        structure: "hough",
        prompt: "a modern office",
        scale: 9,
        a_prompt:
          "best quality, photo from Pinterest, interior, cinematic photo, ultra-detailed, ultra-realistic, award-winning, interior design, natural lighting",
        n_prompt:
          "longbody, lowres, bad anatomy, bad hands, missing fingers, extra digit, fewer digits, cropped, worst quality, low quality",
      },
    }),
  }
);

let jsonStartResponse = await startResponse.json();
```

Comment: Where did you set to no-cors?
Have you tried Axios?

Comment: Yes alwasy triedwith axios same problem.For the example i haven't set the no cors

Comment: CORS policy is something that will handle by API Server side configuration. 
- Have you tried Postman?
- Provide error log.

Comment: I will trie it with postman and give a response here. But if it will work in postman, what does it mean with the above code?

Comment: in Postman you can edit so many request configs. but in Fetch (browser) you cant.

Comment: So now have tried a few things. The following: If I make a cURL everything works. If I create a 1:1 Javascript/ajax POST request from cURL then I get the errors mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making cURL or Postman requests and it's working. It's because of CORS (Cross origin resource sharing) which **can't** be controlled in browser fetch API for security measurements. [read more about cors error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors)

**Solution 1**:
For your development/testing purposes you can Install this extension called [ModHeader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader-modify-http-hea/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj) on Chrome. This allows you to modify any request Header you want.

**Solution 2** (suggested): You have to contact people who has access to API server to change CORS settings for you. (e.g. if the backend API using express and NodeJS you can modify CORS policy using [this link](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html&oe=UTF-8).)

> If API doesn't change from backend you will run into some problems when deploying/shipping your project to the client since the client is not using modHeader extension.

Let me know if you have any further questions

Edit 1:
You can also use [other](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-origin-cors-change/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc) chrome extension